# Linear transformation diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, diagonalization

I encountered this question and I need some assistance to solve it.

$T$ is a linear transformation from $V \to V$

We are given that $T^2 = T$

Show that $T$ can be diagonalized.

Comment: I know that, but who said that T is 2x2? Just because there are 2 distinct roots does not mean it can be diagonalized. what if T is 3x3? in that case you need 3 roots...

Comment: similar to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73862/diagonalization-of-a-projection

Comment: @Katsu It's not only similar, it's the same

Comment: @egreg: Sorry it's not my native language. It's what I meant.

Comment: Regarding your deleted question: $x\equiv a\!\pmod {\!n}\!\iff\! n=n_1n_2\cdots n_k\mid x-a$   

$\!\iff\!n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k\mid x-a\!\iff\!\forall n_i\ (x\equiv a\!\pmod{\!n_i})$   

Remember $\ a,b\mid n\!\iff\! ab\mid n\ $ given $(a,b)=1$,   

which is true because $\ a,b\mid c\!\iff\! \text{lcm}(a,b)\mid c\ $ is the definition of $\text{lcm}$   

and $\text{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{ab}{(a,b)}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Assume it can't, then you can still take it in Jordan's normal form. Derive a contradiction using the condition $T^2=T$.